# How do i set dark mode theme across multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement a dark mode across my website which has 3 different pages. I made 3 separate javascript files to each page and copied the dark mode code to each one.  Now I want to save the preference so that the user doesn't have to keep clicking the dark mode feature every single time they go to a different part of the site. This is what I have that changes it to dark mode. I've seen answers using localStorage but I'm still new to JS so I'm having trouble implementing it. Should I have only one javascript file for all 3 pages or keep it separate files?

```
   <label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="darkmode">
   <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>


let checkbox = document.getElementById("darkmode");
let body = document.getElementById('body')

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
if(this.checked) {
    body.classList.add('dark')
} else {
    body.classList.remove('dark')     
}
});
```

Comment: you can use localstorage

Comment: @dgknca you should post an example in an answer

Comment: You could use cookies or localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick is to use the window.localstorage() or cookies(), this will help you to make this functionality easily. 

For more information, you can see this article [MDN Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
 & [MDN cookies.Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/Cookie)

Practical example always help us 100%, 

This is a better way to do this stuff. 
https:// codepen.io/Md_Tahazzot/pen/xxKLmJa

Comment: It should be the accepted answer. I like your answer!

Comment: Thanks I ended up using localstorage() and found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you can do the following:

- On each page do the following on change:

```
    checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
         localStorage.setItem('dark',this.checked);
         if(this.checked) {
              body.classList.add('dark')
         } else {
              body.classList.remove('dark')     
         }
    });
```

- And on load of each page, do the following:

```
    if(localStorage.getItem('dark')) {
         body.classList.add('dark');
    }
```