# Keep dark or light mode over different pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode

Basically, I got a dark mode on the front page, with the script being (from W3schools) :

```
<script>
function darklightmode() {
    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("dmode");
} </script>
```

And the button :

```
<button onclick="darklightmode()" style="background:none; border: none;">
                        <img src="images/ld-icon.png" class="icon">
                    </button>
```

and some CSS just for example :

```
.dmode li a{
transition: 1s all;
color: #2E3440;
background: none;}
```

So how can I, with some Javascript, make the mode the user is using stay between pages and not come back to default when accessing another page ?

Beginner here, any help appreciated.

Comment: why not save the mode onto cookies or web storage then apply the CSS after reading the saved info this way all pages will stay in the mode the user assigned to it.

Comment: @seriosly basically right but you shouldn't use cookies for it but the local-storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to store the current theme somewhere. Try using localstorage.

Example from [How do i set dark mode theme across multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045285/how-do-i-set-dark-mode-theme-across-multiple-pages) (this question is a duplicate):

```js
    checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
         localStorage.setItem('dark',this.checked);
         if(this.checked) {
              body.classList.add('dark')
         } else {
              body.classList.remove('dark')     
         }
    });
```

and this on each page:

```js
    if(localStorage.getItem('dark')) {
         body.classList.add('dark');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that my dark theme is defined by a class (darkmode) in body tag, in all my html files as:

```
 <body class="darkmode">
```

So, the easiest way to solve the problem by using toggle function and localStorage is:

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const toggleMode = document.querySelector(".toggle");

toggleMode.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let actualTheme = body.className;

  localStorage.setItem("Mytheme", actualTheme);
  body.classList.toggle("darkmode");
});
```

Then (same answer by Sid) in all html files you include:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("Mytheme"))
        body.classList.toggle(localStorage.getItem("Mytheme"));
```